# Is "assign" the same meaning as "copy"?

Tags: objective-c

i know `assign` should be used with primitive variables, such as `BOOL`, `NSInteger`. But i don't know the exactly meaning of `assign` ?

---

e.g.  (my understanding, maybe not right)

```
@property (copy) NSString *strCopy;

@property (strong) NSString *strStrong;

@property (weak) NSString *strWeak;

NSString *anotherStr = @"abc";

self.strCopy = anotherStr;

self.strStrong = anotherStr;

self.strWeak = anotherStr;
```

`strCopy = anotherStr` means `strCopy` gets a **new** data "abc" in memory.

`strStrong = anotherStr` means `strStrong` gets a reference to **current** data "abc", and the reference count of "abc" add 1.

`strWeak = anotherStr` means `strWeak` gets a reference to **current** data "abc", but the reference count of "abc" doesn't change.

---

Another example:

```
@property (assign) NSInteger myNumber;

NSInteger anotherNumber = 10;

self.myNumber = anotherNumber;
```

in this example, `myNumber` actually gets a **new** data '10' in memory. so i think `assign` is just as same as `copy`, is that right?

Comment: Just to be clear, I think you mean `self.strCopy = anotherStr` (etc. for the other examples). That code as written would be directly assigning to an instance variable (which would only work if you provided an explicit `@synthesize` for each property). Updating your question would make it a clearer example for future readers.

Comment: `assign` is just a simple assignment. It copies the data from one variable to another. However, if the data is a pointer/reference, it copies just the pointer/reference. It doesn't create a copy of the target memory. `copy` calls `- [NSObject copy]` method which calls `[NSCopying copyWithZone:]` and then assigns the result. Rather big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `assign` is not the same as `copy`, you are simply confusing pointers with non-pointer values.

In Objective-C, every object is represented using a pointer. When you assign an object pointer to a `copy` property, the runtime sends `- copy` to the original object, and that allocates new memory (it may not as an optimization, but let's assume it does) and **assigns the new pointer** to the instance variable backing the property.

So two things are copied: the object itself (a new object is instantiated in memory, distinct from the old one), and then a pointer to this new object is assigned.

With `assign` properties, however, the language doesn't care whether you've got a pointer-to-object or something else; it just does a regular assignment. It literally just assigns (and thus "copies") whatever is on the right-hand side. If it's a pointer, that's fine – but no new object will be allocated in memory.